# angularjs $http.GET over SSL request cancelled in embedded CEF and Webkit browsers but works in Chrome/FF

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ssl, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I have a small angular app running in a Cefglue .Net browser control. The browser gets to and loads the app just fine but the XHR GET requests in the background get cancelled and never reach the server.

Both the app and the node.js webservice are at https addresses so I know that there isn't a cross domain problem there.

I initially built and tested the app without SSL and it worked fine.

Angular.js version 1.2.5

relevant code:

```
$http({
    url: BaseUrl + '/conversations/' + $scope.conversation.id,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: reqHeaders
    }).then(function(data){ 
            //success       
        },function(errData){
            //nope
        });
    };
```

Comment: SSL? Certificate is valid or it is self-signed?

Comment: Valid SSL certificate

Comment: You probably should enable verbose cef logging and check logs. Also have sense check request-related handlers.